# printing "<" in pdf is not working using iTextSharp

Tags: asp.net, pdf, itext

I have the following text in my web page.

**Footnote This is <1 234234> This is end part should be visible.**

When I convert the web page to pdf the above page is shown as

**Footnote This is This is end part should be visible.**

After analyzing I got that this is happening because of "<".
I guess the reason is that iTextSharp considers <1 234234> as a tag and it doesn't add this text to the pdf.

If we have only "<" in the text and doesn't have ">" then the whole text after "<" is skipped.

Can anyone please suggest how to show the above text properly? Any help will be appreciated.

I have tried by replacing "<" with "&lt" but this did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()` and it is working properly now. :)

If anyone knows anything more then please share.